# Illegal mix of collations (cp1251_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I try to use MySQL in cp1251_general_ci encoding(with russian characters support) in Grails. But when I start my application, while `bootstrap.gsp` executes, I get this error:

```
2015-06-04 15:52:28,889 [localhost-startStop-1] 
    ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Illegal mix of collations (cp1251_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) 
    for operation '='
```

In MySQL I deleted an old database and created new with required encoding, but I get this error still.
What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix really depends on the statement that's throwing the error.

Basically, MySQL is complaining about the expressions on either side of the `=`, that the characterset/collations aren't compatible.

The error is due to a mismatch in charactersets between two expressions being compared.

I usually run into this error when I run a statement that creates an inline view (derived table), and the derived table (as expected) is created with the characterset of the client connection, and then in the outer query an equality comparison is made to a column from a table that has an incompatible characterset, for example:

```
   SELECT l.latin1col
     FROM latin1table l
     JOIN (SELECT 'utf8string' AS utf8col) s
       ON s.utf8col = l.latin1col
```

The characterset of the column in the inline view isn't specified, so the derived table inherits that from the `character_set_connection` variable. One possible fix would be to change the setting of the variable for the session. (Then when the statement runs, the column in the derived table will be that characterset.)

The other fix is specify the characterset for the column in the inline view, e.g.

```
   SELECT l.latin1col
     FROM latin1table l
     JOIN (SELECT _latin1'utf8string' AS latin1col) s
--                ^^^^^^^ 
       ON s.latin1col = l.latin1col
```

---

To fix your problem, you need to figure out which expression is which characterset, and make a suitable adjustment on one side or the other.

That is, is the `cp1251_general_ci` collation coming from the client connection, or is that from the table column.

If you're using a literal in the statement, you can get that converted to a suitable characterset/collation for comparison to a column of a different characterset/collation with a `CONVERT` function...

For example, rather than this:

```
 WHERE col = 'myliteral'
```

You can do something like this:

```
 WHERE col = CONVERT('myliteral' USING latin1)
```

-*or*- with literal values, you can also do this

```
 WHERE col = _latin1'myliteral'
```

If you need to also specify a collation, you can follow that with the COLLATE keyword and specify a collation valid for the characterset:

```
 WHERE col = CONVERT('myliteral' USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

---

It's not clear from your question what the `character_set_connection` and `collation_connection` variables are set to.

```
 SELECT @@session.character_set_connection
      , @@session.collation_connection 
      , @@global.character_set_connection
      , @@global.collation
```

Or what the characterset and collation of the character column(s) in your database are set to,

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

---

**NOTE:**

The characterset setting at the database level is a *default* value that's applied to new tables that are added to the database which do NOT have a characterset/collation defined.

The "default characterset" setting of a table is the characterset that will be used for a new column that is added that doesn't specify a characterset/collation.

Issuing a statement to change the characterset for a table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci
```

does *not* change the characterset or collation for columns that are already in the table. It only affects new columns added that don't have a characterset/collation specified. The same thing applies to an `ALTER DATABASE` statement... that doesn't have any affect on existing tables and columns, only on new tables that are created which don't specify a characterset/collation.

Comment: The `SHOW COLLATION` statement will give a list of valid charactersets and collations for the database. Note that there can be several collations for a characterset, but each characterset has a *default* collation that is used when the collation isn't specified. Also, here's a reference to the MySQL CONVERT( ... USING ...) syntax. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-convert.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-convert.html)  There's more information elsewhere in the MySQL Reference Manual regarding charactersets and collations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was lucky but what I did was change all nvarchar to varchar, I got the error on the 000webhost server and everything worked as it should